# How to control table access in Lightadmin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping, lightadmin

I'm building a back-office application using Spring Boot and Lightadmin. I'd like to limit creation/editing/deletion for some tables (maybe by obscuring respective buttons). Is there a Java configuration to achieve this?

Comment: This question seems a little light on information and perhaps is missing a tag (Java). You may want to read this SO help article: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

For any table that you want to administer in the dashboard, you need to explicitly define a (configuration) class which extends AdministrationConfiguration.

See example [here](http://lightadmin.org/getting-started/registering-entity-for-administration/)

If you don't extend the class for your table, it will not show up in the dashboard.